# ERROR : StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[global]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[global]: NullInjectorError: No provider for global

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I open my ionic project but nothing dispay in browser. I get error like 
[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdlQT.jpg)

this my code in app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
imports: [
  HttpClientModule,
  HttpModule ,
 ],
providers: [
  Clipboard,
{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
 ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
```

Comment: provide your codes, otherwise no-one can understand what is the problem

Comment: It was a newly created project or existing project problem , please explain all in detail .

Comment: Please update with your code

Comment: i have update my question

Comment: Most likey this error occurs when you are trying to use a provider,import or something like that and do not properly declare it in modules file.You may have forgotten to declare it in providers or somewhere else.If you can paste entire code then it will be more easy to identify issue. It will be even better if you can make a stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons 1. If you are using HttpClient in your service you need to import HttpClientModule in your module file and mention it in the imports array.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

2) If you are using normal Http in your services you need to import HttpModule in your module file and mention it in the imports array.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i new in ionic
can you give me example, please?

Comment: you just remove httpmodule from your app.module.ts file and use httpclient in your service like in below:->import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
imports: [
  HttpClientModule
 ],
providers: [
  Clipboard,
{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
 ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })

Comment: Can u make a stackblitz, so that i can go through code.